# Batch writing text to speech audio files from .csv file

Tags: zsh, audio, csv, batch-jobs, text-to-speech

I am new to using ZSH on Mac and am looking for help to write a simple shell script to batch create WAV audio files from a .csv file

I have created a .csv file with data in 3 columns, A B C. Wanting to have text to speech read each line and write that line to a .WAV file

A sample would be:

Folder “TextToConvert”

.csv file “HelloSounds.csv”

```
A, B, C
Hello, my name is, Fred
Hello, your name is, Anne
Hello, is your name, Charles
```

Not sure how to select the voice or have the files named to reflect their content.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You want the entirety of each line as a separate file? (Does it matter that it's csv if each line is treated as a unit?)  Is there a particular tts system you want to use? I know how I would do this on linux using something like festival/flite but am unfamiliar with the default tts engine on mac.

Comment: Hi. Yes, the entire line would become a separate WAV file. Each line would be a unit (ef "Hello my name is Fred") I am new to ZSH and Oh-My-Zsh on a Mac. I do have access to a PC as well.

Comment: Are you new to CSV files, too?

Answer (score 0):

With the following `input` file,

```
% < input
A, B, C
Hello, my name is, Fred
Hello, your name is, Anne
Hello, is your name, Charles
```

We can use `awk` to run the `say` command for each line of input, on the assumption that the final column is the voice name, and that the whole line should be spoken. Spaces are terrible in filenames on unix, so some pains are taken to replace those with underscores.

```
% < input awk '/Hello/{file=$0;gsub(" ","_",file);system("say -v " $NF " -o " file ".wav " $0)}'
Opening output file failed: fmt?
Voice `Anne' not found.
Voice `Charles' not found.
```

However, `say` on my system does not like "*.wav" file types, apparently. So maybe you could create AIFF:

```
% < input awk '/Hello/{file=$0;gsub(" ","_",file);system("say -v " $NF " -o " file " " $0)}'
Voice `Anne' not found.
Voice `Charles' not found.
% file Hello,_my_name_is,_Fred.aiff
Hello,_my_name_is,_Fred.aiff: IFF data, AIFF-C compressed audio
% afplay Hello,_my_name_is,_Fred.aiff
```

And then convert the AIFF to WAV with a program like `ffmpeg` or such?